# Trouble plotting a right triangle at an angle in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, math, geometry, trigonometry

I'm trying to generate a right triangle with hypotenuse = 1, interior angle 25, with its base rotated 30 degrees.  I've entered the trig formulas correctly to my understanding, and I suspect some kind of rounding error.  Because the triangle produced in matplot is slightly off from a right triangle.

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from annotation import label

angle_b = math.radians(25) # the interior 25 degree angle of our right triangle
angle_a = math.radians(30) # 30 degree angle between the plotted angle_b triangle base and the x axis.

point_A = (0,0)
point_B = (math.cos(angle_a + angle_b), math.sin(angle_a + angle_b))
point_C = (math.cos(angle_a) * math.cos(angle_b), math.sin(angle_a) * math.cos(angle_b))

# Label our points
label(plt, 'A', point_A)
label(plt, 'B', point_B)
label(plt, 'C', point_C)

# Draw the right triangle between our points.
plt.plot(*zip(point_A, point_B, point_C, point_A), marker='o', color='black')
```

[image]

As you can see, the angle ACB is not a right angle as [trigonometry would predict](https://socratic.org/questions/derive-the-sine-sum-formula-using-the-geometrical-construction-given-in-the-figu).

@Mad Physicist pointed out a the comment that ABC does appear to be a right triangle.  I would like to get ACB to be a right angle, like [this example](https://socratic.org/questions/derive-the-sine-sum-formula-using-the-geometrical-construction-given-in-the-figu).

Here is with the right triangle formed by angle_a below the previous one:

```
point_D = (math.cos(angle_a) * math.cos(angle_b), 0)
plt.plot(*zip(point_A, point_C, point_D, point_A), marker='o', color='black')
label(plt, 'D', point_D)
```

[image]

Now solved.  I finally got it working thanks to the line `ax.set_aspect('equal')`

[image]

Comment: ACB is not right, but ABC seems to be

Comment: hmmph, how do I get ACB to be? like in this example https://socratic.org/questions/derive-the-sine-sum-formula-using-the-geometrical-construction-given-in-the-figu

Comment: Plot the unrotated triangle along with the rotated one. I'm not at all convinced your rotation formula is correct

Comment: Yes, I believe it is an issue of the formula.  I can update the post with an image of the properly right triangle formed by angle_a

Comment: Also, don't add things like "Edit:" and "Update:" to your question. We can see the edit history as it is. Your question should be the best form of itself you can come up with at any given time. Calling attention to modifications distracts from that purpose

Comment: Updated post with your requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that by default, matplotlib doesn't use the same distances in the x and in the y direction. Instead, matplotlib tries to fit everything nicely into the given bounds.

These uneven distances distort angles, and also deforms circles.

You can force an equal aspect ratio via `ax.set_aspect('equal')`.

To calculate the positions via the angles, and have the right corner at point B, you need to take into account that the length AC is `cos(b)` times the length of AC.  AC can be chosen to have 1 as length. Alternatively, you could divide both B and C by `cos(b)` to have a larger triangle, where the length of AB would be 1.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

angle_b = math.radians(25)  # the interior 25 degree angle of our right triangle
angle_a = math.radians(30)  # 30 degree angle between the plotted angle_b triangle and the x axis.

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(14, 5), sharey=True)

for ax in (ax1, ax2):
    point_A = (0, 0)
    if ax == ax1:
        point_B = (math.cos(angle_a + angle_b) * math.cos(angle_b), math.sin(angle_a + angle_b) * math.cos(angle_b))
        point_C = (math.cos(angle_a), math.sin(angle_a))
        ax.set_title('length AC is 1')
    else:
        point_B = (math.cos(angle_a + angle_b), math.sin(angle_a + angle_b))
        point_C = (math.cos(angle_a) / math.cos(angle_b), math.sin(angle_a) / math.cos(angle_b))
        ax.set_title('length AB is 1')
    point_M = ((point_A[0] + point_C[0]) / 2, (point_A[1] + point_C[1]) / 2)

    # Draw the right triangle between our points.
    ax.plot(*zip(point_A, point_B, point_C, point_A), marker='o', color='black')
    # draw a circle around the 3 points
    ax.add_patch(plt.Circle(point_M, math.sqrt((point_M[0] - point_A[0]) ** 2 + (point_M[1] - point_A[1]) ** 2),
                            ec='r', ls='--', fc='none'))
    ax.set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')

plt.show()
```

[image: right angle at B]

The same calculation works for any angle. Here is how 12 rotations in steps of 30 degrees look together:

[image: 12 rotations]

The following code shows the effect of `ax.set_aspect('equal')` for the original points.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

angle_b = math.radians(25)  # the interior 25 degree angle of our right triangle
angle_a = math.radians(30)  # 30 degree angle between the plotted angle_b triangle and the x axis.

point_A = (0, 0)
point_B = (math.cos(angle_a + angle_b), math.sin(angle_a + angle_b))
point_C = (math.cos(angle_a) * math.cos(angle_b), math.sin(angle_a) * math.cos(angle_b))

point_M = ((point_A[0] + point_B[0]) / 2, (point_A[1] + point_B[1]) / 2)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(16, 4), gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [2, 1]})

for ax in (ax1, ax2):
    # Draw the right triangle between our points.
    ax.plot(*zip(point_A, point_B, point_C, point_A), marker='o', color='black')
    # draw a circle around the 3 points
    ax.add_patch(plt.Circle(point_M, math.sqrt((point_M[0] - point_A[0]) ** 2 + (point_M[1] - point_A[1]) ** 2),
                            ec='r', ls='--', fc='none'))
ax1.set_title('Default aspect ratio, deforms the angles')
ax2.set_aspect('equal')  # or plt.axis('equal')
ax2.set_title('Equal aspect ratio')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: using equal aspect ratio]

Comment: First off, thanks for finding solution with the `ax.set_aspect('equal')`.  Second, I see what I was asking for was not rotation of a triangle so much as placing the base at an angle. So I misphrased my question and your diagram shows what actual rotation would be.  Thanks to @Mad Phys for helping explain my folly here.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have jumbled your trigonometry. I'm going to suggest moving slowly step-by-step, and using variable names that help you remember what is going on.

Let's start with the original triangle. If `interior_angle = np.deg2rad(25)` and the hypotenuse has length `1`, then the right angle on the x-axis is at `(np.cos(interior_angle), 0)` and the other interior angle is at `(np.cos(interior_angle), np.sin(interior_angle))`. Neither of the points in your diagram corresponds.

Now let's express the triangle as a matrix whose columns are the vertices:

```
interior_angle = np.deg2rad(25)
vertices = np.array([
    [0, np.cos(interior_angle), np.cos(interior_angle), 0],
    [0, 0, np.sin(interior_angle), 0],
])
```

The last vertex is a repeat of the origin to make plotting easier.

Now let's look at the rotation. For `rotation_angle = np.deg2rad(30)`, point `(x, y)` rotates to `(np.cos(rotation_angle) * x - np.sin(rotation_angle) * y, np.sin(rotation_angle) * x + np.cos(rotation_angle) * y)`. This can be expressed as a matrix equation:

```
rotation_matrix = np.array([
    [np.cos(rotation_angle), -np.sin(rotation_angle)],
    [np.sin(rotation_angle), np.cos(rotation_angle)]])
p_out = rotation_matrix @ p_in
```

The array `vertices` is so constructed that it can be directly multiplied by a rotation matrix. You can therefore write

```
rotation_angle = np.deg2rad(30)
rotation_matrix = np.array([
    [np.cos(rotation_angle), -np.sin(rotation_angle)],
    [np.sin(rotation_angle), np.cos(rotation_angle)]])
rotated_vertices = rotation_matrix @ vertices
```

The plotted image should make more sense now:

```
plt.plot(*vertices)
plt.plot(*rotated_vertices)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: My trig was correct, all I needed was `ax.set_aspect('equal')`  See https://socratic.org/questions/derive-the-sine-sum-formula-using-the-geometrical-construction-given-in-the-figu - your approach of rotation matrices is just a niftier way to do the trig.  Also note that in the example the triangles share a side

Comment: @bgcode.  How do triangles with a 25 degree internal angle share a side when rotated by 30 degrees?

Comment: Ah.. im starting to think my error was in phrasing as a rotation.. when my intent was just to create a right triangle that seemed to me to be rotated, even though it was just sharing a side/being stacked on the angle below.  i equated angle addition with rotation cus on the unit circle the top triangle seemed rotated.. but its the hypotenuse that rotates.. is that my error?

Comment: yeah.. it cant be rotation because the size of the hypotenuse is not preserved.  my bad.  I updated my post to ask the right question.  I guess my brain just looked at this and thought rotation erroneously..